# Recover files from "Previous System" after reinstalling Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, file-recovery

I have a serious problem with my desktop files in OS X. My system crashed and I installed Leopard, perserving users and network options.

The installation failed and I lost my desktop files. The system created a folder "Previous System", but inside it displays the account and the desktop like a white page.

Is it possible to recover my files?

Comment: Restore from backup.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely just take everything from inside that "Previous Systems" folder. It contains the files of your previous installation.

- You will find stuff that was on your Desktop by going to *Users/dimitris/Desktop* (I assumed your username was "dimitris").
- The same goes for your documents, which should reside under *Users/dimitris/Documents*.
- If you had any applications installed, they're under *Applications*.

You can just drag and drop the files to where you want them.

If however your *Previous Systems* folder does not contain what you want, then you've probably lost your files and you need to restore from a backup.